# Supertest and jest: cannot close express connection

Tags: express, jestjs, supertest

I am using jest and supertest to raise instance of express and run tests on it.

I faced with the problem of busy port that cannot still solve.

In my test I do the next:

```
import supertest from 'supertest';
const agent = supertest(app);
```

Then I go requests with agent and everything works fine.
Until I am running another test.
In app.js I have:

```
var app = express();

app.post('/auth/changePassword',VerifyToken, auth.changePassword);

app.listen(4001, function () {
    console.log('Server is running');
});
```

So first spec runs perfect. But second tries to listen to the port that is already in use.
I really do not know how to close the connection here.

I tried `app.close()` but got error that such method. This is clear, that I have to assign

```
server = app.listen(4001, function () {
    console.log('Server is running');
});
server.close();
```

But do not know how can I do that.
I also tried to preset agent in jest.setup and assign it to global variable

```
import app from "../../server/app";
import supertest from 'supertest';

const agent = supertest(app);
global.agent = agent;
```

But situation is the same, first test passed, second tries to raise express on the same port.

Answer (score 5):

Supertest is able to start and stop your app for you - you should never need to explicitly kill the express server during the tests (even when running in parallel)

The problem is that in `app.js` your server is actually started - this means that when the app tests are run your server is started every time `app.js` is read (or once per test case)

You can remedy this by splitting the `server start` logic into a seperate file, so that importing `app.js` doesn't start the app (rather returns an express server instance) The pattern I normally use for this is:

```js
// app.js
import express from 'express'
export const app = express();

app.get("/example", (req,res) => {
  return res.status(200).json({data: "running"})
})

// server.js
import app from "./app"

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening on 3000"));

// app.spec.js
import app from "./app"
import request from "supertest"

it("should be running", async () => {
  const result = await request(app).get("/example");

  expect(result.body).toEqual({data: "running"});
});
```

Comment: i have the same setup and it still fails

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this is to make sure that `NODE_ENV` isn't set to `'test'` before allowing express to listen for connections.

```
if (process.env['NODE_ENV'] !== 'test') {
  app.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`[ ready ] http://${host}:${port}`);
  });
}
```